# Clip rasters and vectors simultaneously in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.3, clip

I am trying to clip an aerial map in QGIS 2.18 with the layers simultaneously in this map:

[image]

My purpose is to get the aerial map clipped by the red layer that includes all layers like this image (i did that image with draw software):

[image]

whereas the result of the clipper is without the blue circle layer:

[image]

The clip function in: vector-> processing tool-> clip, clips only vectors.

In Raster-> clipper, it clips only raster by the mask layer.

In ArcGIS 10.3 this function is called "clip to shape" and the whole map- rasters and vectors been clipped by polygon shape.

[image]

Is there an equal function to "clip to shape" in QGIS 2.18 the same as in ArcGIS?

Comment: Never heard of clip to shape tool in Arcgis. Makes me wonder what sort of output it might produce

Comment: The tool Raster -> Clipper as you point out can do the job. The mask layer can be a vector layer, in your case your red layer, so the result will be your aerial map clipped by the red layer

Comment: i update the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how exactly `Raster --> Extraction --> Clipper...` works. You can also use `Clip raster by mask layer` from processing toolbox. Both running `gdalwarp` command.

As mask layer you have to choose vector layer, the raster will by clipped to vector layer extent rectangle, but all values outside of shape will be `nodata` if you leave the no data value option unchecked, it will remain `0` (intiger).

[image]

If you want to crop the extent to the shape check `Crop the extent of the target dataset to the extent of the cutline` option.

*update:*

I thing there isn't build-in tool for clip raster and vector layer at once. But it can be easily created with graphical modeler or python custom processing tool. Create model with `Clip raster by mask layer` for raster and `Clip vectors by polygon` for vector. The model should looks like:

[image]

Once you have working model saved, you can run it as a batch process for as many different raster and vector inputs you want.

For creating models and batch processing see QGIS documentation:

[The graphical modeler](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html)

[The batch processing interface](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html)

Comment: i update the question

Comment: @newGIS ok, now I see it, I'll update my answer